# jQueryを使わずにサイドバー固定

Tags: html, css

サイドバーにfixedを使い、height100%にすればスクロールしても固定できますが、ヘッダーが80pxあった場合、スクロールした時に上に80px分余白が飽きます。

サイドバーにtop0にし、ヘッダーをrelativeにしてzindexをサイドバーより低くすれば空白は飽きませんが上に80px分余白が空きます。paddingも同じです。

どうにかいい案はありませんか？

Comment: どのようなレイアウトを作りたいのか、シンプルで良いので図示できませんか?

Answer (score 1):

こういうことか？

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <style type="text/css"><!--
      body {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
      }
      #header {
        width: 100%;
        height: 80px;
        position: fixed;
        color: white;
        background-color: black;
        z-index: 2;
      }
      #sidebar {
        width: 25%;
        height: 100%;
        padding-top: 80px; /* #header@height */
        position: fixed;
        background-color: darkgray;
        z-index: 1;
      }
      #contents {
        margin-left: 25%; /* #sidebar@width */
        width: 75%;
        padding-top: 80px; /* #header@height */
        height: auto;
        background-color: lightgray;
        z-index: 0;
      }
    --></style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="header">ヘッダ</div>
    <div id="sidebar">サイドメニュー</div>
    <div id="contents">
      <p>Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample
      Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample
      Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample
      Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample
      Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: 違います。
ヘッダーは固定しません。
メインコンテンツの後にサイドバーが無いとSEO的に悪いです

Comment: であればあなたが元にしてるコードか図を出してください。

Comment: @user10678 過度に攻撃的なコメントだったので、コメントの文面を修正しました。